# Create a case record Daily, Weekly and Monthly

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I need to create a case that we can set a frequency to auto create a new case record daily, weekly and monthly.

I was thinking that an apex trigger will be needed. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: With the limited information you have provided I can only suggest that this is a batch process not a trigger.  Triggers operate after an interaction with the database e.g. a user doing something on an API call modifying the database.  If you want something to happen on a schedule then you need a batch that runs every day and evaluates some conditions and creates a record if required.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there is not much information regarding business process on why a case needs to be created so the code below needs to be extended to incorporate that logic

```js
public with sharing class CaseCreatorJob implements Database.Batchable < SObject > , Database.AllowsCallouts {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    System.debug('CaseCreatorJob Started.....!');
    return Database.getQueryLocator('select id from Case where SomethingToGoWith__c = true');
  }

  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Case > cases) {
    list < Case > caseForInsert = new list < Case > ();

    for (Case sb: cases) {
      Case newCase = new Case();

      // update some fields
      caseForInsert.add(newCase);
    }

    insert caseForInsert;
  }

  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    System.debug('CaseCreatorJob Completed.....!');
  }
}
```

You would then use the APEX scheduler within the admin setup to set this batch to run at the frequency and time you need it to.

For full details check out https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm